# PostgreSQL: Calculate balance working backwards from current balance

Tags: postgresql, recursive

I have a `balances` table that stores the `current_balance` for bank accounts; and a `transfers` table that contains a row for every transfer to- and from an account (deposits are positive numbers, withdrawals are negative).

I need to create an account summary that contains each transfer for an account, as well as the balance resulting from that transfer.

**Example:**

```
+--------------------------+--------+---------+
|      activity_date       | amount | balance |
+--------------------------+--------+---------+
| 2015-12-24T20:27:00.670Z |     10 |     180 |
| 2015-12-19T12:13:50.085Z |   -275 |     170 |
| 2015-12-18T23:56:22.513Z |     10 |     445 |
| 2015-12-18T23:54:46.880Z |     50 |     435 |
| 2015-12-17T03:32:10.707Z |   -120 |     385 |
| 2015-12-12T03:56:50.775Z |     35 |     505 |
| 2015-12-11T23:09:40.211Z |    -20 |     470 |
| 2015-12-03T01:17:59.460Z |    -10 |     490 |
| 2015-11-23T15:39:35.003Z |    500 |     500 |
+--------------------------+--------+---------+
```

Since I only have the current balance for the account, I need to start there and work my way backward to a given date. In a spreadsheet, I would calculate the new balance by subtracting the amount of the transfer from the previous balance, but I'm having trouble translating this into SQL.

### Schema

```
CREATE SCHEMA temp;

CREATE TABLE temp.balances (
  account_id      INT
, current_balance INT
);

CREATE TABLE temp.transfers (
  account_id      INT
, activity_date   TIMESTAMP
, amount          INT
);

INSERT INTO temp.balances (account_id, current_balance)
VALUES (1, 180);

INSERT INTO temp.transfers (account_id, activity_date, amount)
VALUES (1, '2015-12-24T20:27:00.670Z', 10)
, (1, '2015-12-19T12:13:50.085Z', -275)
, (1, '2015-12-18T23:56:22.513Z', 10)
, (1, '2015-12-18T23:54:46.880Z', 50)
, (1, '2015-12-17T03:32:10.707Z', -120)
, (1, '2015-12-12T03:56:50.775Z', 35)
, (1, '2015-12-11T23:09:40.211Z', -20)
, (1, '2015-12-03T01:17:59.460Z', -10)
, (1, '2015-11-23T15:39:35.003Z', 500);
```

### SQL

```
WITH transfers AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM temp.transfers
  WHERE account_id = 1
    AND activity_date BETWEEN '2015-10-01'::DATE AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ORDER BY activity_date DESC
)
SELECT
  t.activity_date
, t.amount
, (LAG(balance, 1, b.current_balance) OVER (ORDER BY t.activity_date DESC)::INT) - (LAG(t.amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY t.activity_date DESC)::INT) AS balance
FROM transfers t
JOIN temp.balances b ON b.account_id = t.account_id
```

This query fails because I am trying to access the value of balance that is being generated by the window function. I looked into [WITH RECURSIVE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html), which seems like the right technique to use, but couldn't get it to work. I'm also not sure if it can be used in conjunction with other WITH clauses, which I would need to do.

So my question is: How can I calculate the balance after each transfer, working backward from the current balance, in **PostgreSQL 9.3**?

### Update

Using a slightly-modified version of Julien's answer below, I tried this:

```
WITH transfers AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM temp.transfers
  WHERE account_id = 1
    AND activity_date BETWEEN '2015-10-01'::DATE AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
SELECT
  t.activity_date
, t.amount
, b.current_balance - SUM(t.amount) OVER(ORDER BY t.activity_date DESC) AS balance
FROM transfers t
JOIN temp.balances b ON b.account_id = t.account_id
```

...which is *almost* correct, except that the balances are shifted up one row.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I am using `current_balance` as the default value in my first `LAG` function call.

Comment: Oh, ok, I just noticed the `insert .. values ...;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify Julien's query to use (as a starting point) the `current_balance` from the other table:

```
SELECT t.account_id, t.activity_date, t.amount,
       b.current_balance - COALESCE(SUM(t.amount) OVER w, 0)  AS balance
ORDER BY account_id, activity_date DESC ;
FROM temp.balances AS b
  JOIN temp.transfers AS t
    ON t.account_id = b.account_id
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY t.account_id 
             ORDER BY t.activity_date DESC
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                      AND 1 PRECEDING) 
ORDER BY account_id , activity_date DESC ;
```

Comment: It should be `b.current_balance + t.amount - SUM(t.amount) OVER ...` when working in `DESC` order, but yes this is the correct solution.

Comment: Yes, I had that right but somehow mixed it up in my head and reversed before posting. I edited with a slightly less complicated way (without using the current `amount` in every row calculation)

Answer (score 7):

You need a Window Function indeed. However LAG is not the right one. `SUM(...) OVER(...)` is the one you want. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5291/4/0).

#### Query:

```
SELECT account_id, activity_date, amount
    , SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY activity_date) as balance
FROM transfers t
ORDER BY account_id, activity_date DESC;
```

#### Output:

```
account_id  | activity_date                 | amount    | balance
1           | 2015-12-24 20:27:00.6700000   | 10        | 180
1           | 2015-12-19 12:13:50.0850000   | -275      | 170
1           | 2015-12-18 23:56:22.5130000   | 10        | 445
1           | 2015-12-18 23:54:46.8800000   | 50        | 435
1           | 2015-12-17 03:32:10.7070000   | -120      | 385
1           | 2015-12-12 03:56:50.7750000   | 35        | 505
1           | 2015-12-11 23:09:40.2110000   | -20       | 470
1           | 2015-12-03 01:17:59.4600000   | -10       | 490
1           | 2015-11-23 15:39:35.0030000   | 500       | 500
```

Comment: I started out with this, but I was using `ORDER BY activity_date DESC` in the `OVER` clause, which was mucking things up. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, this isn't correct. The reason I am using `DESC` is because I need to be able to query a date range that does not necessarily include the first transfer (the initial deposit). So I need to work backwards from the current balance, but this solution works forward from the first transfer. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should edit the question. It should also work in the other direction. I can't look at it right now.